# Update TeamCity Build Number with version in Gradle build script

Tags: gradle, teamcity, build.gradle, gradle-task, gradle-git

I have a gradle build script as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
         //Some repo
    }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.8.0"
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.git-version'

version gitVersion()
```

I would like to update TeamCity `build number` with the value of `version` from the `gitVersion()` function. Is there anyway to  do that?

I know in Maven world, for TeamCity to pick-up the version in `pom.xml` file, I can specify TeamCity build number equal to `%maven.project.version%`. But how to achieve the same thing with Gradle?

***An attempt:***

Also, I thought of a solution to create a Gradle Exec task to update TeamCity build number via **Service Message** (doc [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)):

```
task updateTeamCityBuildNumber(type: Exec) {
    x=version
    echo $x
    echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='buildNumber' value='${x}']"
}
```

But I got this error:
`Could not set unknown property 'x' for task ':updateTeamCityBuildNumber' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec`

So another question on this direction is that how do I pass the variable `version` into the Gradle Exec task and refer to it in the "echo" statement below?

(My TeamCity build agent is Linux)

Thanks and let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `echo` command with

```
println "##teamcity[buildNumber '${version}']"
```

There is also a documentation [page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Gradle) on Confluence.

Comment: `task updateTeamCityBuildNumber {
 println "##teamcity[buildNumber '${version}']"
}`
This is the final code that works, based on @grundic answer

Answer (score 0):

As of TeamCity Professional 2017.2 (build 50574) original variant

```
println "##teamcity[setParameter name='buildNumber' value='${x}']"
```

is working again.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs How exactly does it _not_ answer the question? Review more carefully, please.